# Quantifying stitching effects

Tags: fourier-transform, stitching, image-processing

I have many images like this with high stitching, medium stitching, low stitching, and no stitching effects (the adjectives high, medium, low and no are purely subjective). How to quantify the amount of stitching that happens in each image since I want to eliminate images with high stitching? Thanks.

P.S We tried Fourier transform to isolate high frequency components but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your subjective lablelling of these example images is suggesting a metric that is related to the mosaicking artifact in your image stitching algorithm. Therefore, I would suggest trying different edge detection algorithms and see which one can better isolate the edges in your images. BTW, your images look quite noisy which is problematic for any high pass filter (e.g., an edge detector), therefore, it makes sense to consider some pre-smoohting in the first place.